# Mysql - alter table

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, alter-table, alter

I want to add new column in my table with date, but I want to give value 000-00-00 in timestamp format to existing record and current_timestamp to new records. Is it possible? how?

Comment: Please provide the table you have currently

Comment: I have got a table with id, name, surname,login, password and i want to add new column created_at, but records wchich are in database now must have date 0000-00-00 but records which I will add in the future must have date of creating account=current_date

Answer (score 0):

First do an UPDATE on the existing records

```
update table set date1 = '0000-00-00';
```

Then Change the column

```
alter table test1 change column date1 date1 timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```